# Enso Launcher: dead or lives on? where?

Tags: software-rec, development, launcher

I just discovered Enso Launcher, and seems it's a tool I always dreamed about (even tried to made some part of its functionality myself).

But it seems, it dead now, and community Enso is only fork of Enso 1.0, and there is no Enso 2.0 functionality.

Is there any maintained successors or alternatives, which allow to extend themselves by commands written in custom languages?

Comment: are you talking about this product: http://www.humanized.com/enso/launcher/?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Executor supports custom languages, but is a very *powerful* launcher tool for Windows...Can create your own custom keywords, etc, so perhaps if you type the keyword in a different language, it will support it?

Check it out: http://www.executor.dk/  - *highly recommend*, worth a try...

Launchy is a more famous program launcher, but personally have no experience with...open source for Windows and Linux, do not know if it supports custom keywords...

Check it out: http://www.launchy.net/index.php

Answer (score 0):

As of today (November 2011), **there's a prototype of the 2.0 version of Enso Launcher.** It's a little rough around the edges, but it's the direction they want to go with their products in general. There's also a developer version that *lets you write your own commands.*

So yes, it's very much under active development; you can look at the comments and see that for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The most recently active fork is on GitHub:

- [GChristensen/enso-portable: Portable Enso Launcher community edition](https://github.com/GChristensen/enso-portable)

The community fork hasn't been active since August of 2011:

- [Code : Enso Project](https://code.launchpad.net/enso/+code?field.lifecycle=CURRENT&field.lifecycle-empty-marker=1&field.sort_by=newest+first&field.sort_by-empty-marker=1)